# How to ignore double quotes when reading CSV file in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a CSV file like:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
"A,B","C", D"
```

I want to read it as a data frame in spark, where the values of every field are exactly as written in the CSV (I would like to treat the `"` character as a regular character, and copy it like any other character).

Expected output:

```
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|  "A|  B"| "C"|  D"|
+----+----+----+----+
```

The output I get:

```
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
| A,B|   C|  D"|null|
+----+----+----+----+
```

In pyspark I am reading like this:

```
dfr = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true")
```

I know that if I add an option like this:

`dfr.option("quote", "\u0000")`

I get the expected result in the above example, as the function of char `'"'` is now done by `'\u0000'`, but if my CSV file contains a `'\u0000'` char, I would also get the wrong result.

Therefore, my question is:
**How do I disable the quote option, so that no character acts like a quote?**

My CSV file can contain any character, and I want all characters (except comas) to simply be copied into their respective data frame cell. I wonder if there is a way to accomplish this using the escape option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the documentation for [`pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=agg#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv) (emphasis mine):

> quote – sets a single character used for escaping quoted values where the separator can be part of the value. If None is set, it uses the default value, ". *If you would like to turn off quotations, you need to set an empty string.*

```python
dfr = spark.read.csv(
    path="path/to/some/file.csv",
    header="true",
    inferSchema="true",
    quote=""
)
dfr.show()
#+----+----+----+----+
#|col1|col2|col3|col4|
#+----+----+----+----+
#|  "A|  B"| "C"|  D"|
#+----+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a work around, if the option suggested by @pault doesn't work -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
df = spark.createDataFrame([('"A,B","C", D"',),('""A,"B","""C", D"D"',)], schema = ['Column'])
df.show()
+-------------------+
|             Column|
+-------------------+
|      "A,B","C", D"|
|""A,"B","""C", D"D"|
+-------------------+

for i in list(range(4)):
    df = df.withColumn('Col'+str(i),split(df.Column, ',')[i])
df = df.drop('Column')
df.show()
+----+----+-----+-----+
|Col0|Col1| Col2| Col3|
+----+----+-----+-----+
|  "A|  B"|  "C"|   D"|
| ""A| "B"|"""C"| D"D"|
+----+----+-----+-----+
```